# how to increase count by 1 in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using the below  code to get the number of records.

```
self.size.to_s
```

How can i add '1' to the size from above?

Comment: Why do you want to add 1 to the size of the object?

Comment: You can increment the size and convert to a string or convert to a string and increment: `"99".next => "100"`. If `size` is not an accessor, you shouldn't need `self.`, as `self` is assumed to be the receiver if one has not been specified.

Answer (score 3):

[`Integer#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Integer.html#method-i-next):

```
self.size.next.to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

`(self.size + 1).to_s` # Like this

Answer (score 0):

You can either add it before converting to string

```
(self.size + 1).to_s
```

Or if you already have a string

```
"2".to_i + 1
```

Combined this could be something like

```
self.size.to_s.to_i + 1
```

but that is hardly practical